# Communication between .net mvc project and arduino with esp8266

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, arduino, esp8266

I have a project about smart home with arduino. I made a mvc web page and it should be send data to arduino with esp8266 wifi module.

But I don't know that how should ı do? So it will be grateful if you guys help me?

Comment: you can refer this link https://www.intertech.com/Blog/iot-with-an-esp8266-part-3-aspnet-core-project-and-database-setup/

Comment: thanks but not enough for now...